# Big array C++ , vector no memory

Tags: c++, arrays

I need huge array in C to store some data. The thing that i am working on is related to DNA sequencing. I am using Visual Studio 2013.

Firstly, I've tried with a global static variable like

```
static oligo SPECTRUM[C1][C2]
```

Where oligo structure contains eight integers, and C1 is 100000 and C2 500.

But visual said that the array is to large. Then I asked Google, and he said that's good idea to use vectors. So i switched to these by replacing code above with a code below

```
static std::vector<std::vector<oligo>> SPECTRUM;
```

It was said that is a nice thing to resize vector before using, so i did:

```
SPECTRUM.resize(C1);
for (int i = 0; i < C1; i++)
{
    SPECTRUM[i].resize(C2);
}
```

but now I am having runtime exception throwed during execution of above code (resizing)

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException' occurred in ConsoleApplication1.exe
```

in file xmemory0. Visual shows the exception is throwed here

```
else if (((size_t)(-1) / sizeof (_Ty) < _Count)
    || (_Ptr = ::operator new(_Count * sizeof (_Ty))) == 0)
    _Xbad_alloc();  // report no memory
```

I want you to know also, that I have 4 GB RAM avaiable on my computer, and I estimate that my program shouldn't use more then 1 GB RAM.

Comment: I've just edited. It was misleading, true. I have 4GB mounted on MoBo, and 2GB is currently avaiable.

Comment: Why are you compiling 32 bit ?

Comment: Define `BIG`, we can't help otherwise

Comment: If it's really big, you'll need to use memory-mapped file. If it isn't, `malloc` will be enough

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each `oligo` will consume 32 bytes. That means that if `C1` is "around 100k", and `C2` is bigger than about 600, the array will consume an entire 2 GB.

Comment: -1, the question is about how to create a big array, not to make silly multiplications.

Comment: Not sure what you're getting at there. You do know how to calculate the size of an array, right? In 32-bit mode, without PAE, creating an array larger than 2 GB -- no matter how you do it -- is not going to work.

Comment: +1, this question is about failing to create a huge array, the reason, that it won't fit into memory is very reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

First are you sure you need all that memory available in your heap(ram)?

-You can do you calculations in chunks, allocate a chunk work on it and free it.

-You can use a file to store all your data, and load chunks of the file for your calculations.

If you need many GB of memory, it's not good to allocate it all at once in the heap, you never know there will be enough left.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt there is a simple solution to this problem, given the values that you are dealing with, you will need more memory or at the very least more address space (this is "the addressable region of memory"). The easiest solution would be to go with an OS that is 64-bit - you may also need to get more RAM, but the first step is to allow the processor to address all the locations in the matrix - and with 32 bits, your limit for C2 becomes around 600, if C1 is 100k. And that assumes there are absolutely no other usage of memory - which unfortunately isn't typically true. The first few megabytes are reserved to catch "null pointer", and then the code and stack has to live somewhere. Ultimately, 100k x 500 seems unlikely to fit, even if the total size allows this much.

The other option is to use a "sparse array". Often when working with large matrices, there is a common value that is in "most places", and only some positions in the large matrix has a "different value". In these cases, you can use a method where you check if the data is present, and if so, use the value, otherwise use the default. You can use for example `std::map` as the storage container, and use the `find` method to see if the data is present.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to address the question other way.

Make a Linked list (refer to data structure concept) for each and every element of the array as Node and get it linked. An pointer would be sufficient for accessing current node.

Yes mechanism function has to be written for traversing linked list, but will help to create such big arrays in the current target operating system instead of shifting to 64 Bit.

Answer (score -1):

You should thry this:

```
static oligo *spectrum[C1];
for(int i = 0; i < C2; ++i)
{
   spectrum[i] = new oligo[C2];
   if (spectrum[i] == nullptr)
   {
     fprintf(stderr, "failed to allocate the array for i=%d.\n", i);
     fflush(stderr);
   }
}
```

this will tell you, how much memory are you allowed to allocate and what is your memory limit.
There may be some linker option to control this limit...

Comment: this won't even give the correct result as you forget a `delete` ..., and why the C output functions instead of `cout`/`cerr`?

Comment: I don't like streams in c++; anyway this question is marked as a c and c++ question.